# Calculated Values of Mass and Area in Simple CAD Program are Very Incorrect

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

```
# NG 
import tkinter as tk

# Create the main window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Simple CAD")

# Define the size of the canvas inches
CANVAS_WIDTH = 5
CANVAS_HEIGHT = 5

# Define the size of the window pixels
WINDOW_WIDTH = 500
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500

# Conversion factor to convert inches to pixels
INCHES_TO_PIXELS = 100

# Canvas for user to draw shape
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=CANVAS_WIDTH * INCHES_TO_PIXELS, height=CANVAS_HEIGHT * INCHES_TO_PIXELS)
canvas.pack()

# Create a list to store the coordinates of shape
shape_points = []

# Define function for mouse movement on the canvas
def handle_mouse_event(event):
    # Check if the mouse pointer is within bounds of canvas
    if 0 <= event.x <= CANVAS_WIDTH * INCHES_TO_PIXELS and 0 <= event.y <= CANVAS_HEIGHT * INCHES_TO_PIXELS:
        # Add the coordinates of the mouse event to the list of shape points
        shape_points.append((event.x, event.y))

        # Draw traced shape on the canvas
        if len(shape_points) > 1:
            canvas.create_line(shape_points[-2], shape_points[-1])

# Bind mouse inputs to the canvas
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", handle_mouse_event)
canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", handle_mouse_event)
canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", handle_mouse_event)

# Define function to calculate area and volume of shape
def calculate_area_and_volume():
    # Check if the shape is closed
    if shape_points[0] != shape_points[-1]:
        # Add the first point to the end of the list to close the shape
        shape_points.append(shape_points[0])
        
    # User inputted extrude value 
    extrude_length = float(input("Enter the extrude length in inches: "))

    # Calculate area of the shape in in^2
    area = 0
    for i in range(len(shape_points) - 1):
        x1, y1 = shape_points[i]
        x2, y2 = shape_points[i + 1]
        area += (x1 * y2) - (x2 * y1)
    area = abs(area) / 2

    # Vol calculation of object  in in^3 
    volume = area * extrude_length

    # Output values 
    print("Area:", area, "in^2")
    print("Volume:", volume, "in^3")

# Create button to close (fully define SolidWorks :/ traced shape
close_button = tk.Button(window, text="Close Shape", command=calculate_area_and_volume)
close_button.pack()
# Create button to calculate the area and volume
calculate_button = tk.Button(window, text="Calculate Area and Volume", 
command=calculate_area_and_volume)
calculate_button.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

Basically, this is a passion project of mine as a MechE student. I wanted to make a VERY simple CAD program with Python (the only language I know) in which a user can sketch an object, and then define a value for its thickness (extrude in CAD). To my knowledge, I have done the shoestring formula correctly for calculating area--basically just a derivation of Herons' Formula right?

Unfortunately, something is wrong because the canvas is set to 5x5 inches and this should theoretically mean absolute maximum area would be 25in^2, but when I tried drawing a square, it came out to be around 20,000 in^2. It was definitely not a perfect square, but if anything the area should have been less than 25 in^2.

I thought this was maybe an issue of the shape not being fully defined and therefore having near infinite area, but I implemented two different ways to make sure this doesn't happen. The first is a GUI button on the canvas that the user can click and it will close the shape for them. Even if they do not end up clicking this button, there is a second checker before the calculations to make sure that the shape is closed.
There's also a possibility I messed up the Shoestring formula like I alluded to above but that doesn't seem very likely.
I'm at a complete loss for why the calculations are this off and any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is because you forgot to convert the pixels (x, y) back to inches.  You need to divide the area by `(INCHES_TO_PIXELS * INCHES_TO_PIXELS)`.

Comment: Yes, this worked! I understand why this is necessary but can you please explain why the value is squared? Thank you so much :)

Comment: Since area is in *unit square*.